# Installing workbench on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, workbench

I am trying to install MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 20.04, and I run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install mysql-workbench
```

the error is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench
```

I used this way to install before but now I do not know what to do, please help, I am new in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### try this:

download `snapd` service using `apt-get`

> sudo apt-get install snapd

after that install workbench

> sudo snap install mysql-workbench-community

when it's done You need to enter a command to allow this package to access the service. The command is:

> sudo snap connect mysql-workbench-community:password-manager-service :password-manager-service

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the repository in your `source.list` file:

```bash
echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ eoan mysql-tools" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
```

then:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install mysql-workbench-community
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has updated their repository for Focal Fossa and removed the repository for Eoan Ermine. To install MySQL Workbench on 20.04, either download the Workbench for 20.04 from MySQL archives or follow the alternate method mentioned below replacing eoan with focal.

Refer this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230752/mysql-workbench-not-supporting-with-ubuntu-20-04-lts