# Install MySQL workbench on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql-workbench, ubuntu-20.04

I have ubuntu server 20.04 without GUI, I followed this answers [installing-workbench-on-ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61739072/installing-workbench-on-ubuntu), I could installed it, but when I try to run the command *mysql-workbench*, it tells me that the "command not found". So my question is, Can I not install mysql workbench on a server without GUI? Is it not supported?

Comment: with or without GUI?   MySQL workbench is a GUI tool, so you will need ubuntu with GUI.

Comment: When you do not have a GUI, you can always use: `mysql-client-8.0`

Comment: Thanks @Luuk, I have a mistake spelling, It's without. But you already anwser I cannot. Thanks.

Comment: Mysql Workbench is a GUI program. It cannot possibly run on a server that has no GUI capabilities. Use either a command line only tool or a remote computer with a normal user interface.

Answer (score -1):

if mysql-workbench and server is installed: open terminal then /usr/bin/mysq-workbench should pull up the workbench screen.